# For Python 3.8 Azure data lake Gen 2, how do I check if a file exists on a filesystem?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Python 3.8, Azure Data Lake gen 2 and the following plugins ...

```
azure-storage-blob==12.4.0
azure-storage-file-datalake==12.1.1
```

How do I check if a specific path exists on a file system?  I tried this

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient

...
            file = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string(
                DATA_LAKE_CONN_STR, 
                file_system_name=filesystem, 
                file_path=path
            )
```

but am getting an error that the "exists" method does not exist for DataLakeFileClient .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a file exists on a filesystem, please refer to the following code

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient

account_name = 'testadls05'
account_key = 'CpfCQot******JOLvB+aJOZbsQ=='
file_system_name='test'
file_client = DataLakeFileClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https",
        account_name
    ),
    file_system_name=file_system_name,
    file_path='test.txt',
    credential=account_key 
)

try:
     file_client.get_file_properties()
except Exception as error:
    print(error)    
    if type(error).__name__ =='ResourceNotFoundError':
        print("the path does not exist")
```

[image]

Comment: I was kind of hoping there was a less hacky way of figuring out the answer (somethign that naturally returns true/false), but an answer is an answer.

Answer (score 5):

A much easier way to test file or path existance:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
...
try:
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")
    if file_system_client.get_file_client("my-file").exists():
        print("file exists")
    else:
        print("file does not exist")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Change `get_file_client()` to `get_directory_client()` for testing a path.

Comment: This is much less hacky than the accepted answer.